# Setting up specific Node.js version for a React Native project

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, nvm

I am facing an issue while trying to run an old React Native project (version 0.67) on my Mac. The problem seems to be related to OpenSSL, and it occurs when using Node.js version 18, which is the default on my system. However, when I switch to Node.js version 16 using nvm, the project runs without any issues.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. I used nvm to switch to Node.js version 16 by running `nvm use v16.20.1` and `nvm alias default v16.20.1`. This successfully
   allowed me to run the project without errors.
2. I considered upgrading the React Native version for this project to
   be compatible with Node.js version 18, but the process seemed to be
   complex and time-consuming.

Now, I have multiple projects on my machine, some of which require Node.js 18. Switching back and forth between Node.js versions using nvm is becoming cumbersome. Is there a way to configure this specific React Native project to use Node.js version 16 when running it, while keeping my other projects on Node.js version 18?

Any guidance on how to set up a specific Node.js version for a React Native project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To fix the `open-ssl` what i did was i created a `.npmrc` then added `node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"` to that. seems like this fixed the issue for now.

Answer (score 4):

I use NVM to manage node versions for a number of react-native projects. I have found that when starting a project from the terminal, metro will start using whatever the alias'd default node version is, and not the version specified by `nvm use`.

So, prior to starting up a particular project i will ensure that i run both (for example):

```
nvm alias default v18.18.0
nvm use v18.18.0
```

If i need to swap back to some other version, i will do the same thing:

```
nvm alias default v16.16.0
nvm use v16.16.0
```

I use `nvm list` to verify my settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

### Good news

The good news is that almost all editors allow you to set the node version as the default value and run exactly this version of NodeJS for the same project, without third-party software.

### First option

Using the WebStorm IDE as an example:
Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js -> this set node version -> apply and ok.

### Second option

```
scripts: {
   "preinstall": "nvm install 0.12.1",
   "prestart": "nvm use 0.12.1", // <= This will install the correct node version before starting
   "start": "node ./file1.js"
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you include in "most editors," but there's no automatic Node bin path switching in many editors. Having an `nvm install` as a preinstall isn't ideal because it will run a whole install on every `npm i` in cases like `nvm i 16.0` if there have been changes to the patch version. And just a nitpick, `nvm use` doesn't install the Node version, it changes PATH to point to that version.

Answer (score 0):

The below options are likely irrelevant — I'm not an `nvm` user so wasn't aware of the config, but you can [set Node versions per project in a .npmrc file](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc).

Other options:

Docker (or other container systems, or VMs) are a good solution for this, and a common way to handle requirements for specific runtime versions in production.

Using the [OpenSSL legacy provider](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0#openssl-3.0) is also an option, but I would not recommend doing this long-term because it may not be supported in the future, and may lead to security issues.

Another option is to install Node itself as a local dependency. You can do that with the package [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) by installing at a specific version. This is a hacky workaround, but because of the folks who worked on it, it seems trustworthy.

Comment: Installing node as a local dependency sounds interesting, can you guide me through this? in my project directory i did, `npm i node@16.20.1` which added `node` as a dependency, now when i run the project via `npx react-native run-ios` it's still picking `node 18` from my machine, am i supposed to run it someother way?

Comment: Are you running `npx react-native run-ios` from inside that project, and is `react-native` installed in that project? `npx` _should_ prepend `node_modules/.bin` to `$PATH` — if you `ls node_modules/.bin` from project root, do you see an executable `node` in there? And a simple test: `npx node --version`, does that report the expected 16.20.1?

Comment: Oh, and I just found this (I don't use `nvm` so wasn't aware of it): https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc

Comment: I do not have `react-native` installed on my machine. and yes there is an executable `node` inside `node_modules/.bin`. when i run `npx node --version` it shows `v16.20.1`. but when i run it' still showing 
```
{
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```
this error on my `metro` terminal.

Comment: i'm not a big fan of `nvm` either i switched back from `nvm` to normal `node` installation using `homebrew`, i use `alias` inside my `.zshrc` to use multiple versions now, i tried `nvm` when that was still showing me this errors.

Comment: Also i did try it with `.nvmrc` i wasn't working..! what worked for me was adding the `.npmrc` with `node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"`

Comment: It sounds like the project's version of Node might've been compiled rather than downloaded from a binary, if you're still seeing that error, or there might be something going on with Metro detecting your global Node version for some reason. If using the OpenSSL 1.1 provider works, that's an easy fix for the time being.

Comment: Yeah, guess i'll go with the OpenSSL 1.1 for now. Then maybe upgrade my RN version later on.